# Implementing Binary Tree in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary-tree, stack-overflow

I've been trying to implement BinaryTree class in Ruby, but I'm getting the `stack level too deep` error, although I don't seem to be using any recursion in that particular piece of code:

```
1.  class BinaryTree
2.    include Enumerable
3.      
4.      attr_accessor :value
5.      
6.      def initialize( value = nil )
7.          @value = value
8.          @left = BinaryTree.new  # stack level too deep here
9.          @right = BinaryTree.new # and here
10.     end
11.     
12.     def empty?
13.         ( self.value == nil ) ? true : false
14.     end
15.         
16.         def <<( value )
17.           return self.value = value if self.empty?
18. 
19.           test = self.value <=> value
20.           case test
21.             when -1, 0 
22.                 self.right << value
23.             when 1 
24.                 self.left << value
25.           end
26.         end     # <<
27.     
28.  end
```

Edit: My question has gone a little bit off track. The current code setting gives me the `stack level too deep` error at line 8.  However, if I employ Ed S.'s solution

```
@left = @right = nil
```

then the `<<` method complains saying: `undefined method '<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` at line 22.

Could anyone suggest how to resolve this?  My idea is that if I could somehow tell the `BinaryTree` class that variables `left` and `right` are of instances of `BinaryTree` (i.e. their type is `BinaryTree`) it would all be well. Am I wrong?

Comment: Every time you call BinaryTree.new, it hits the `initialize` method and calls another BinaryTree.new, and repeats forever. That's why your stack is overflowing

Answer (score 13):

> although I don't seem to be using any recursion in that particular piece of code:

Yet...

```
def initialize( value = nil )
    @value = value
    @left = BinaryTree.new  # this calls initialize again
    @right = BinaryTree.new # and so does this, but you never get there
end
```

That is infinite recursion.  You call `initilize`, which in turn calls `new`, which in turn calls `initialize`... and around we go.

You need to add a guard in there to detect that you have already initialized the main node and are now initializing leafs, in which case, `@left` and `@right` should just be set to `nil`.

```
def initialize( value=nil, is_sub_node=false )
    @value = value
    @left = is_sub_node ? nil : BinaryTree.new(nil, true)
    @right = is_sub_node ? nil : BinaryTree.new(nil, true)
end
```

---

To be honest though... why aren't you just initializing left and right to nil to begin with?  They don't have values yet, so what are you gaining?  It makes more sense semantically; you create a new list with one element, i.e., elements left and right don't yet exist. I would just use:

```
def initialize(value=nil)
    @value = value
    @left = @right = nil
end
```

Comment: I would just have one additional question to it.  Is that a standard way to initialize attributes which are of type the class in which they appear?  I'm not sure if I asked the right way.

Comment: @Maputo: Yes, you define a method named `initialize` and that is what is called when someone calls `YourType.new`.  You should just set left and right to nil.  It makes more sense and it solved the infinite recursion problem.

Comment: If I do that, I'm getting than other problems with the << function which I'm overriding.  Check out the source again please, I've just edited it.

Comment: @Maputo: Ok, so you have another error in your code, that doesn't mean your initial approach was correct.  You're never *assigning* `value`, you simply call that method recursively over and over again.  If you're going to use recursion you need a guard which determines when to stop, i.e., when to *assign* `value` and exit the process.

Comment: What I don't get in Ruby is how you create a class BinaryTree (for example) that has BinaryTree attributes.

Comment: Actually, I think I do.  The first line of the << method returns the value as soon as it hits an empty leaf. Or at least I think it does...

Comment: @Maputo: I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Here is a Java equivalent. 
`Class BinaryTree { BinaryTree left, right; int value; }` How do you do that in Ruby?

Comment: @Maputo: You initialize them to `nil`. Variables aren't typed in Ruby, values are.

Answer (score 2):

```
1.  class BinaryTree
2.    include Enumerable
3.      
4.      attr_accessor :value
5.      
6.      def initialize( value = nil )
7.          @value = value
8.      end 
9.      
10.     def each # visit
11.         return if self.nil?
12.         
13.         yield self.value
14.         self.left.each( &block ) if self.left
15.         self.right.each( &block ) if self.right     
16.     end
17. 
18.     def empty?
19.         # code here
20.     end
21.         
22.     def <<( value ) # insert
23.         return self.value = value if self.value == nil
24. 
25.         test = self.value <=> value
26.         case test
27.             when -1, 0
28.                 @right = BinaryTree.new if self.value == nil
29.                 self.right << value
30.             when 1 
31.                 @left = BinaryTree.new if self.value == nil
32.                 self.left << value
33.         end
34.     end     # <<
35.  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to fix the infinite recursion in your code. Here's a working example of a binary tree. You need to have a base condition to terminate your recursion somewhere, else it'll be a stack of infinite depth.

Example of Self-Referential Data Structures - A Binary Tree

```
class TreeNode
  attr_accessor :value, :left, :right

  # The Tree node contains a value, and a pointer to two children - left and right 
  # Values lesser than this node will be inserted on its left
  # Values greater than it will be inserted on its right
  def initialize val, left, right
    @value = val
    @left = left
    @right = right
  end
end

class BinarySearchTree

  # Initialize the Root Node
  def initialize val
    puts "Initializing with: " + val.to_s
    @root = TreeNode.new(val, nil, nil)
  end

  # Pre-Order Traversal
  def preOrderTraversal(node = @root)
    return if (node == nil)
    preOrderTraversal(node.left)
    preOrderTraversal(node.right)
    puts node.value.to_s
  end

  # Post-Order Traversal
  def postOrderTraversal(node = @root)
    return if (node == nil)
    puts node.value.to_s
    postOrderTraversal(node.left)
    postOrderTraversal(node.right)
  end

  # In-Order Traversal : Displays the final output in sorted order
  # Display smaller children first (by going left)
  # Then display the value in the current node 
  # Then display the larger children on the right
  def inOrderTraversal(node = @root)
    return if (node == nil)
    inOrderTraversal(node.left)
    puts node.value.to_s
    inOrderTraversal(node.right)
  end

  # Inserting a value
  # When value > current node, go towards the right
  # when value < current node, go towards the left
  # when you hit a nil node, it means, the new node should be created there
  # Duplicate values are not inserted in the tree
  def insert(value)
    puts "Inserting :" + value.to_s
    current_node = @root
    while nil != current_node
      if (value < current_node.value) && (current_node.left == nil)
        current_node.left = TreeNode.new(value, nil, nil)
      elsif (value > current_node.value) && (current_node.right == nil)
        current_node.right = TreeNode.new(value, nil, nil)
      elsif (value < current_node.value)
        current_node = current_node.left
      elsif (value > current_node.value)
        current_node = current_node.right
      else
        return
      end
    end
  end
end

bst = BinarySearchTree.new(10)
bst.insert(11)
bst.insert(9)
bst.insert(5)
bst.insert(7)
bst.insert(18)
bst.insert(17)
# Demonstrating Different Kinds of Traversals
puts "In-Order Traversal:"
bst.inOrderTraversal
puts "Pre-Order Traversal:"
bst.preOrderTraversal
puts "Post-Order Traversal:"
bst.postOrderTraversal

=begin

   Output :
     Initializing with: 10
   Inserting :11
   Inserting :9
   Inserting :5
   Inserting :7
   Inserting :18
   Inserting :17
   In-Order Traversal:
     5
   7
   9
   10
   11
   17
   18
   Pre-Order Traversal:
     7
   5
   9
   17
   18
   11
   10
   Post-Order Traversal:
     10
   9
   5
   7
   11
   18
   17

   =end
```

Ref: http://www.thelearningpoint.net/computer-science/basic-data-structures-in-ruby---binary-search-tre

Answer (score 0):

@pranshantb1984 - The ref you gave is good one but I think there is a small change in code. Need to update PreOrder and PostOrder code as given below

```
# Post-Order Traversal
def postOrderTraversal(node= @root)
    return if (node == nil)
    postOrderTraversal(node.left)
    postOrderTraversal(node.right)
    puts node.value.to_s
end 

# Pre-Order Traversal
def preOrderTraversal(node = @root)
    return if (node == nil)
    puts node.value.to_s
    preOrderTraversal(node.left)
    preOrderTraversal(node.right)
end
```

**Pre Order Traversal**

10 -> 9 -> 5 -> 7 -> 11 -> 18 -> 17

**Post Order Traversal**

7 -> 5 -> 9 -> 17 -> 18 -> 11 -> 10