# How to Store and Retrieve a Hash by an Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to build a hash that is used to store a directory. I want to have multiple levels of keys. At the match point, I want an array of files. It is like a directory structure on a computer. It seems a hash is the best way to do this.

Given that I have an array of folders `["folder1", "folder1a", "folder1ax"]`, how do I:

1. Set a hash using the folder structure as the key and the file as the value in an array, and
2. Query the hash using the folder structure?

I'm using this to parse out URLs to show them in a folder structure, and it's very similar to dumping into JSTree in a Rails app. So, if you have a better alternative for how to display 5000 URLs that works great with Rails views, please provide an alternative.

Comment: You might want to look into [binary-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree). This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205180/implementing-binary-tree-in-ruby) could be a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a starting point:

```
dirs = %w(Downloads)
Hash[ dirs.map{ |dir| [dir, Dir.glob("#{dir}/*")] } ]
```

This is the result:

```
{"Downloads"=> ["Downloads/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.zip", ... ] }
```

You can refine the code f.e. making it recursive, removing the folder name from the array results... this is an example of recursive implementation:

```
class Dir
  def self.ls_r(dir)
    Hash[ dir,
      entries(dir).reject{ |entry| %w(. ..).include?(entry) }.map do |entry|
        entry_with_dir = File.join(dir, entry)
        File.directory?(entry_with_dir) ? ls_r(entry_with_dir) : entry
      end ]
  end
end

puts Dir.ls_r('~/Downloads').inspect 
#=> { "Downloads" => ["file1", {"Downloads/folder1"=>["subfile1"], ... ] } ... }
```

Note that this is not the best implementation, because the recursion doesn't take in consideration that the children folders keys should be relative to the respective parent keys; to resolve this issue, this info should be maintained through the recursion:

```
class Dir
  def self.ls_r(dir, key_as_last_path_component = false)
    Hash[ (key_as_last_path_component ? File.split(dir).last : dir),
      entries(dir).reject{ |entry| %w(. ..).include?(entry) }.map do |entry|
        entry_with_dir = File.join(dir, entry)
        File.directory?(entry_with_dir) ? ls_r(entry_with_dir, true) : entry
      end ]
  end
end

puts Dir.ls_r('~/Downloads').inspect
#=> { "Downloads" => ["file1", {"folder1"=>["subfile1"], ... ] } ... }
```

and now the children folders are relative to their parent keys.